# Debug the following ruby code to successfully complete my program for String class

Tags: ruby, debugging, logic

> So I was trying redefine strings to behave as that of expressions in algebra like "x" + "1" should return "x + 1" and not "x1" , "x - 1"*"x + 1" should return "x² - 1" and not undefined and similiar things as we do with polynomials.
> So I'd made some good methods to deal with simple operations but one thing I'm stuck at from a long time is debugging my defined String::simplify method which always shows some error when used in the program
> .
> Suspicious methods :
> `String::simplify`, `String::simplify2` & `String::minus`
> Error giving example :
> `puts ("x - 1"*"x + 1").simplify` => it results an error saying comparison of nil with 2 failed at line 138 inside the `String::minus` method

**Hope it makes it more clearer to identify the glitch in logic or somewhere else**

```
class String

  @@powers = %w(⁻ ˙ ⁰ ¹ ² ³ ⁴ ⁵ ⁶ ⁷ ⁸ ⁹)

  @@store = Hash[(["-","."]+[*"0".."9"]).zip @@powers]

  @@reply = "Sorry ,super strings can't tolerate your madness"

  def monomial?;self.terms.size == 1end

  def polynomial?;!self.monomial?end

  def * b #multiplication

    if(self.polynomial? or b.polynomial?)

      s = []

      self.terms.each do |i|

        b.terms.each do |j|

          q = i._ j

          q.end_with?("x¹") ? s << q.chomp("¹") : s << q

        end

      end

      return s.join " + "

    end

    self._ b

  end

  def _ b #multiplication of two terms

    @negative = 1

    @negative *= -1 if self.include? "-"

    @negative *= -1 if b.include? "-"

    self.gsub!("x","x¹") if self.scan(/[⁰¹²³⁴⁵⁶⁷⁸⁹]+/).empty?

    b.gsub!("x","x¹") if b.scan(/[⁰¹²³⁴⁵⁶⁷⁸⁹]+/).empty? 

    self.gsub!("x","1x") if self.scan(/\d+/).empty?

    b.gsub!("x","1x") if b.scan(/\d+/).empty? 

    m = "#{@negative}".scan(/\D+/).join

    x = "#{self.scan(/\d+/).join.to_i * b.scan(/\d+/).join.to_i}x#{(self.scan(/[⁰¹²³⁴⁵⁶⁷⁸⁹]+/).join.unsup.to_i + b.scan(/[⁰¹²³⁴⁵⁶⁷⁸⁹]+/).join.unsup.to_i).to_s.sup}".gsub(/(\D*)(1x)/,"\1x")

    if x.scan(/\d+/).empty?

      x.gsub! "x⁰","1"

    else

      x.gsub! "x⁰",""

    end

    return "0" if (m+x) == "-0"

    return m+x

  end

  def sup;self.gsub /\S/,@@store;end #from normal to supersrcipt string

  def unsup #from superscript to normal string

    self.gsub /[⁻⁰¹²³⁴⁵⁶⁷⁸⁹]/,@@store.invert

  end

  def ** n;([self]*n).reduce :*end #exponentiation of expression 

  def degree #degree of polynomial 

    z = self.dup

    z.gsub!("x","x¹") if z.scan(/[⁰¹²³⁴⁵⁶⁷⁸⁹]+/).empty?

    z.terms.map{_1.scan(/[⁰¹²³⁴⁵⁶⁷⁸⁹]+/).join.unsup.to_i}.max

  end

  

  def a b #addition of two terms

    self.gsub!("x","1x") if self.scan(/\d+/).empty?

    b.gsub!("x","1x") if b.scan(/\d+/).empty?

    if self.degree == b.degree

      x = "#{self.scan(/\d+/).join.to_i + b.scan(/\d+/).join.to_i}x#{b.degree.to_s.sup}"

      if x.scan(/\d+/).empty?

        x.gsub! "x⁰","1"

      else

        x.gsub! "x⁰",""

      end

      x.chomp!("¹") if x.end_with? "x¹"

      return x

    end

    return (a + " + " + b).gsub "+ -","-"

  end

  def terms;self.gsub("-","+ -").split " + "end #to get the terms of an expression in array

  

  def simplify #to simplify the given expression

    return self.simplify2 unless self[1..].include? "-"

    a = self.terms

    p = a.reject{_1[0] == "-"}.join(" + ").gsub("+ -","-")

    n = (a.select{_1[0] == "-"}).map{_1[1..]}.join(" + ").gsub("+ -","-")

    p.minus n

  end

   

  def simplify2 #to simplify the expression containing only positive sign terms

    a = self.terms

    e = a.map &:degree

    ex = self.ex

    h = Hash[ex.zip([[]]*a.size)]

    a.size.times{h[e[_1]] += [_1]}

    s = []

    for i in ex.sort.reverse

      s << h[i].map{a[_1]}.reduce(:a)

    end

    s.join(" + ").gsub "+ -","-"

  end


  def add b #addition of two expressions

    (self + " + " + b).gsub("+ -","-").simplify2

  end

  def describe #describing the type of polynomial

    "Yep,so #{self} is degree #{self.degree} polynomial"

  end

  def coeff #to get the coefficient of a term

    return @@reply if self.polynomial?

    self.gsub! "x","1x" if self.scan(/\d+/).empty?

    self.scan(/-*\d+/).join.to_i

  end

  def coeffs #to get the coefficients of the terms in array

    return @@reply if self.monomial?

    self.terms.map{_1.gsub! "x","1x" if _1.scan(/\d+/).empty?;_1.scan(/-*\d+/).join.to_i}

  end

  

  def m b #to subtract two terms

    if self.degree == b.degree

      c,d = self.coeff - b.coeff,b.degree

      return "0" if c.zero?

      if d.zero?

        return "#{c}x#{b.degree.to_s.sup}".gsub "x⁰",""

      elsif d == 1

        return "#{c}x#{b.degree.to_s.sup}".gsub "x¹","x"

      end

      return "#{c}x#{b.degree.to_s.sup}"

    end

    (self + " - " + b).gsub "- -","+"

  end

  

  def - b

    return @@reply if self.polynomial? or b.polynomial?

    self.m b

  end

  def minus b #subtraction of two expressions

    a,b = self.simplify2,b.simplify2

    s = []

    e1,e2 = a.terms.size,b.terms.size

    e3,e4 = a.terms.map(&:degree),b.terms.map(&:degree)

    m = [a.degree,b.degree].max

    h1 = Hash[[*m.downto(0)].zip([[]]*(m+1))]

    h2 = Hash[[*m.downto(0)].zip([[]]*(m+1))]

    e1.times{h1[e3[_1]] += [_1]}

    e2.times{h2[e4[_1]] += [_1]}

    m.downto(0){

      if h1[_1].empty? && h2[_1].empty?

        #shoot the user

      elsif h1[_1].empty?

        s << "-#{b.terms[h2[_1][0]]}"

      elsif h2[_1].empty?

        s << "#{a.terms[h1[_1][0]]}"

      else

        s << a.terms[h1[_1][0]].m(b.terms[h2[_1][0]])

      end

    }

    s.join(" + ").gsub("+ -","-").gsub(/[+-] 0 /,"").terms.join(" + ").gsub "+ -","- "

  end

  def ex;self.terms.map(&:degree).uniq;end

  

  def negative?;self[0] == "-"end #checking whether the term is negative or not

  

  def positive?;!self.positive?end #checking whether the term is positive or not

end


class Array

  def form #defining this method to convert the array returned by terms to reform the expression

    self.join(" + ").gsub "+ -","-"

  end

end
```

Comment: Instead of posting all your code, it would be much better if you only posted a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Which means: Only the method that causes the error, the input you used that generated the error, the expected output and the error message including the stack trace.

Comment: Thanks for responding lemme simplify the question i asked for the community to answer

Comment: Please remove excessive blank lines. This code example is long, but it's made *way* longer from all the empty space.

Comment: Tip: Instead of directly injecting code in `String` or another class like this, consider making a `module` and then `include` that in any target class(es) that need it. This makes it *way* easier to test.

Comment: Sorry sir but can u also tell how to use modules for this purpose in my case ?

Comment: Where do the three quotes at the beginning of your question come from? Please, make sure to attribute your quotes properly.

Answer (score 2):

> Error giving example :
> `puts ("x - 1"*"x + 1").simplify` => it results an error saying comparison of nil with 2 failed at line 138 inside the `String::minus` method

Method `*` with `return s.join " + "` yields `x² + x + -x + -1`; given this, method `simplify` gets `a = self.terms` as `x²`
`x`
`+ -x`
`+ -1` (due to `terms;self.gsub("-","+ -")` adding an extra `+` , then `.split " + "`), so `n = (a.select{_1[0] == "-"})…` is empty (due to no term beginning with `-`) at `p.minus n`; method `minus` with `m = [a.degree,b.degree].max` where `b` is the actual parameter `n` finally fails because `b.degree` yields `nil` for the empty string.

> So , what should be done for it ?

In order to fix just the problem of splitting into the additive terms without prepending `+`  you could change `terms`:

```
  def terms; self.split(/ \+ | (?=- )/) end
```

Comment: So , what should be done for it ?